# How do I convert a json array into an array php can read?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

**Answer**

Thanks to Kenneth's answer and suggestions, I did figure out what I needed to do. There's an added layer because this is an ExpressionEngine site, but basically I needed to tell the function that the variable was coming in from the post, like this:

```
$newItems = $this->EE->input->post('newItems');
$newItems = json_decode($newItems, true);
```

**UPDATED**

After following Kenneth's suggestion below, I was able to get the javascript to recognize that I was passing in `r.newItems`. But my php function doesn't recognize that it's receiving an array. This is the error I'm getting:

```
PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for Order::addReorderToCart()
```

My php function looks like this:

```
public function addReorderToCart($newItems) {
        error_log("newitems");
        error_log(print_r($newItems,1)); // this is not printing anything
        $_SESSION['order']['items'] = array_merge($_SESSION['order']['items'], $newItems);
        $this->EE->app->addToCart();
        $rtnArray['success'] = true;
    }
```

What do I need to do to translate the array that's being sent through the jquery so that the php function recognizes it as an array?

I have the following javascript/jquery code that runs as a result of another ajax call:

```
function ohReorderAjaxReturn(data) {
    console.log("ajax return");
    console.dir(data);

    var r = eval(data);
    console.log("r");
    console.dir(r);

    if(data.unavailableItems instanceof Array && data.unavailableItems.length > 0) {
        // there are unavailable items; ask if they want to go ahead

        Modal({
            title: r.errTitle,
            text: r.errMsg, // need to update this to contain correct text including store address and unavailableItems
            yellow_button: {
                btn_text: "It's OK, continue",
                action: function(r){
                    console.log("r inside function");
                    console.log(r);
                    // need ajax call to addReorderToCart
                    $.post('/site/ajax/order/addReorderToCart',  {'newItems': r.newItems},
                    function(data) {
                        var ret = eval(data);

                        if( ret.success == 1 ) {
                            document.location = '/site/order_summary';
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            black_button: {
                btn_text: "Cancel"
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("not an array");
    // there are no unavailable items; add to cart and continue on
    }
}
```

A `console.log` right inside the `if(data.unavailableItems instanceof Array && data.unavailableItems.length > 0)` line lets me know that it gets that far. It is popping up the modal, but the `action` part (which calls another php function via ajax) doesn't seem to be getting the `newItems` value passed in. Here's a screenshot of Firebug; you can see that the `console.dir(r)` a few lines inside the function signature returns information for `newItems`. Why does `r` become undefined when I try to pass it into the post? And how can I do it, if what I'm doing now is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Why `eval`? Are you using it just as a JSON parser?

Comment: I'm adding to code that someone else wrote a while back. The eval has always worked until we added this new bit of functionality, so I didn't change it.

Comment: +1, thanks for `console.dir`.

Comment: Can you post the Order class ? Or otherwise the code that is invoked by the action url.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you define `r` as a parameter of your function and when the function is called it's not passing a value and thus the parameter is hiding the access to your outer variable. You should remove the parameter and then your outer variable will become visible inside the function again:

```
** snip **
yellow_button: {
                btn_text: "It's OK, continue",
                action: function(){   // removed r as a parameter
                    console.log("r inside function");
                    console.log(r);
** snip **
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I already tried that, but I've gone through so many permutations that maybe I missed this one. I'll try it again.

Comment: Hm. OK, that got me past that part, but my php error log is showing that addReorderToCart isn't receiving a parameter. So for some reason, `r.newItems` is not actually making through from the javascript to the php.

Comment: Is your PHP expecting JSON?

Comment: Ah, that could be the problem. No, it isn't. So if I use `json_decode($newItems)` in my php, that should fix it? I'll give it a shot.

Comment: No, it probably won't fix it. Your PHP is looking for form values, not JSON. I'm not familiar with PHP so you'd have to look somewhere else for that question

Comment: It's really not, though. The function is expecting an array. There's nothing in the function that's asking specifically for form variables.

Comment: Like I said, I'm not an expert on PHP, you need to make it so that it expects JSON (and don't forget to stringify your JSON with `JSON.stringify` before posting it to the server. Also you might want to use `$.ajax` instead of `$.post` and set the correct content-type